# When AND operator is used with ternary one result is unexpected

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Could someone please explain why expression below is resolved to `true` ¯_(ツ)_/¯

`false && 'no matter what' ? true : true`

Comment: You are returning true regardless of the conditional.

Comment: Well you've got `true` on both sides of the ternary operation. The `&&` is a higher-precedence operator than `? :` so everything to the left of `?` is the predicate expression.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect the expression to resolve to something else?

Comment: sure, && operator has higher precedence so it should act first, it should be resolved to the first falsy value we have `false` falsy value on the left, so no matter what we have in ternary operator it should be resolved to `false`

Comment: When the expression is true, the operator will return what is after the "?" symbol. When the expression is false, the operator will return what is after the ":". So, nothing to be surprised of. Basically you are telling: "if true give me true, otherwise, give me true"

Comment: )))))) Oh, my bad, thanks you all!

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your expressions in parenthesis to give them more precedence.

```
false && ('no matter what' ? true : true)
```

`&&` has more precedence over a ternary.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to fix it!) Just curious current behavior

Answer (score 2):

Taking the reference from the below concept

```
true && true     => true
true && false    => false
true || true     => true
true || false    => true
false && true    => false
false && false   => false
false || true    => true
false || false   => false
```

### 'no matter what' ? true : true will return true

### false && true will return false

```
console.log(false && ('no matter what' ? true : true))
```

Output:
false

Adding a parentheses will solve the problem

Comment: your question is alright, but it would be simpler if you said "&&" means 'and', so statement **AND** statement (if statements are true) returns true, and, "||" means 'OR', so statement **OR** statement (if one of the statements is true) returns true. then solve the problem